# If I use an CC by Attribution 4.0 image in my application, am I required to make my app CC-BY 4.0 too?

Tags: creative-commons

I want to use image that was licensed as CC by Attribution 4.0 in my application. Is there any requirements about licensing my whole application? Should it be CC-BY 4.0 too, or can I use different license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose any (or no) license for your application. You just have to attribute the image correctly.

If [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) were a [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) license, you would have to license your application under this (or a compatible) license, too. But CC BY 4.0 isn’t a copyleft license. Creative Common’s copyleft licenses all have "SA" (which stands for "ShareAlike") in their name (e.g., [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)).